# Piping a python output into an Ansible variable

Tags: ansible

I have a python script that outputs a hash.  I would like that hash to be piped into my variable inside of the ansible script.

The Python command looks like this-

```
#!/bin/python
import crypt
test= crypt.crypt('test', '$6$Som3S@lt$')
print test
```

My ansible playbook looks like this -

```
 hosts: webservers
  remote_user: test
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  vars:
      pass:


  tasks:

  - name: Run Python Password script
    command: /home/test/userPW.py > pass
```

Thanks

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/537060/how-to-see-stdout-of-ansible-commands. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294923/are-ansible-puppet-chef-salt-questions-on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with register.

```
➜  ~ cat test.yml
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  user: jenkins
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: password
      shell: cat /tmp/pass
      register: pass

    - debug: var=pass.stdout

➜  ~ ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml


PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [password] ****************************************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "pass.stdout": "mypassword"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```